# Check if 3 in a row array value is same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if my array has 3 same values which are in a row.

For example

```
var arr = ["g", "z", "z", "z" ]; // Must be true

var arr = ["g", "z", "z", "v" ,"b", "b", "b"]; // Must be true

var arr = ["z", "g", "z", "z"]; // Must be false
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zw8erea3/)

**How can we check it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check the predecessors.

```js
function check3(array) {
    return array.some(function (a, i, aa) {
        return i > 1 && a === aa[i - 2] && a === aa[i - 1];
    });
}

console.log(check3(["g", "z", "z", "z"]));                // true
console.log(check3(["g", "z", "z", "v" ,"b", "b", "b"])); // true
console.log(check3(["z", "g", "z", "z"]));                // false
console.log(check3(["z"]));                               // false
console.log(check3(["z", "z"]));                          // false
```

With a dynamic approach for any wanted length

```js
function check(array, length) {
    var count = 0,
        value = array[0];

    return array.some(function (a) {
        if (value !== a) {
            count = 0;
            value = a;
        }
        return ++count === length;
    });
}

console.log('length: 3');
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "z"], 3));                // true
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "v" ,"b", "b", "b"], 3)); // true
console.log(check(["z", "g", "z", "z"], 3));                // false
console.log(check(["z"], 3));                               // false
console.log(check(["z", "z"], 3));                          // false

console.log('length: 4');
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "z", "z"], 4));           // true
console.log(check(["g", "z", "z", "b" ,"b", "b", "b"], 4)); // true
console.log(check(["z", "z", "z", "a"], 4));                // false
console.log(check(["z"], 4));                               // false
console.log(check(["z", "z"], 4));                          // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: close, but no bounds check?

Comment: This  `check3(["a","b","b","b","c","a"])` will return `true`, I think it should return `false`, isn't it ?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas, why? is has three `'b'` in a row.

Comment: No it must be true, 'b' in a row. @MohamedAbbas

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most performant approach would be to iterate over the input-array only once and count streaks of consecutive equal elements. When a long enough sequence is found, return true immediately. When the end was reached, return false.

```js
function hasConsecutive(arr, amount) {
    var last = null;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != last) {
            last = arr[i];
            count = 0;
        }
        count += 1;
        if (amount <= count) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutive(["g", "z", "z", "z"], 3))
console.log(hasConsecutive(["g", "z", "z", "z"], 4))
```

Comment: Thats so nice, we can even set the amount!

Answer (score 2):

Pass the array in this function ,

```
check3inRow(dataArray)
{
        for(i=0 ; i < (dataArray.length-2) ; i++ )
        {
            if(dataArray[i] == dataArray[i+1] && dataArray[i+1] == dataArray[i+2])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Will not check each element in array like forEach does and also validates the array if it has more than 2 values else it will directly return false , will ignore last two elements as there is no need to comparing those last two element.

**Less checking , less looping , will get you faster result.**

Comment: The outer check isn't actually necessary - the `for` loop will be skipped entirely if the array length isn't greater than 2 because of the `i < length - 2` guard

Comment: @Alnitak , that was not , shown in code that's why I added it and also , its checks only to the third last element              i < (dataArray.length-2)

Comment: so it will saves your time , @Alnitak , if dataArray.length > 2 is not needed we can remove it.

Comment: You're missing my point.   If the array is too short, the `for` loop won't go through any iterations because it _immmediately fails the loop condition in the `for` statement_.  e.g.. if `length == 2` then for `i = 0` the test `0 < 2 - 2` becomes `0 < 0` which is `false` so the `for` loop never even starts.

Answer (score 1):

And a little quicker with only 2 additions per item

```
function testFor3InARow(arr){
    var i = 0,len = arr.length-2;
    while(i < len){
       if(arr[i++] === arr[i] && arr[i] === arr[i+1]){
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And sacrificing one iteration step for the false result can reduce execution time with only one addition per item

```
function testFor3InARow(arr){
    var p = false,i = 0,len = arr.length -2;
    while(i <= len){
        if(p){
            if(p = (arr[i++] === arr[i])){ return true }
        }else{
            p = arr[i++] === arr[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Update : After some testing looks like the first method is the quickest at  153µs ±1µs per 1000 random arrays 0-100 items with 10% having a randomly located tripple. THe second method got 193µs ±0µs for the same data.

I have tested some of the other answers and got the following results

```
Performance test. : 'Test for 3 in a row'
Use strict....... : true
Duplicates....... : 4
Cycles........... : 3078
Samples per cycle : 100
Browser.......... : Firefox 53.0b9 (32-bit)
OS............... : Windows 10 (32-bit)
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By Blindman67 method A' Mean : 175µs ±2µs (*) 51635 samples
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By Blindman67 method B' Mean : 212µs ±1µs (*) 50989 samples
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By obyFS' Mean : 260µs ±0µs (*) 51211 samples
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By Nina Scholz' Mean : 392µs ±2µs (*) 51384 samples
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By fafl' Mean : 209µs ±1µs (*) 51433 samples
---------------------------------------------
Test : 'By Vivek Doshi' Mean : 188µs ±2µs (*) 51148 samples
-All ----------------------------------------
Mean : 0.239ms Totals time : 73680.010ms 307800 samples
(*) Error rate approximation does not represent the variance.
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure that using `i++` and `i` in the same expression is deterministic?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes this is Javascript.

Comment: Unless you can quote chapter and verse from the language spec, I wouldn't be so sure...   It wouldn't be legal in many other languages, and IMHO that makes it a bad idea.

Comment: @Alnitak The spec guarantees the order and it is not something a JS engine would overlook. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: operator precedence is _not_ the same thing as order of evaluation.  AFAIK there is no guarantee that the right hand side of the `===` will not be evaluated until after the left hand side with the `i++` operator.  This quote (albeit relating to Java) is relevant: _"It is considered poor style to write code that relies upon this behavior (and different programming languages may use different rules)"_ (from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: in C and C++ this would be explicitly _undefined behaviour_, but someone translating your code from JS into C might not know that

Comment: @Alnitak Your quote is but the author's opinion and irrelevant, nor should effective language use be define by other languages. JS can not do concurency (ie floating point and integer on seperate ALUs) the reason for C/C++/Java indeterminate expresion evaluation, and thus JS can  *"JavaScript evaluates an expression according to a predefined order of precedence"* https://books.google.com.au/books?id=vS6t524rE1sC&lpg=PA96&ots=VB0pP9P8QL&dq=differences%20of%20order%20of%20expression%20in%20javascript&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=differences%20of%20order%20of%20expression%20in%20javascript&f=false

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very naive but like [@fafl 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43309028/4543207) my contribution would be a general one which would return `n` number of same consecutive items. Here i test it with a 1,000,000 item array filled with random integers among 0..9 and tests for 6 consecutive items, resolving in less than 200ms.

```js
function itemsInRow(a,n){
  return a.reduce(function(r,e,i){
                    r[0][i%n] = e;
                    r[0].every(x => x === r[0][0]) && r[1].push(r[0].slice());
                    return r;
                  }, [Array(n).fill(),[]])[1];
  
}

var arr = Array(1000000).fill().map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*10));
    res = [];
console.time("itemsInRow");
res = itemsInRow(arr,6);
console.timeEnd("itemsInRow");
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```js
function checkIfThreeConsecutive(arr) {
  var bool = false;

  arr.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if (index > 1 && (arr[index] == arr[index - 1]) && (arr[index] == arr[index - 2])) {
      bool = true;
    }
  });
  return bool;
}

console.log(checkIfThreeConsecutive(["g", "z", "z", "z"]));
```

Comment: the `.some` function short circuits the test as soon a a match is found

Comment: @Alnitak true and it will save few micro-seconds given that OP's hasn't mentioned that he/she is going to run in on an array of millions. I agree though that `.some` would be a better choice. I didn't think of it till I saw it on one of the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop

```js
var arr = ["g", "z", "z", "v", "b", "b"];
var i, l = arr.length,
  status = false;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
    if (arr[i + 1] == arr[i + 2])
      status = true;
  }
}
console.log(status)
```

Comment: This is so close to my solution. I must have made typo tho :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple with bounds check

```
function checkIf3InRow(arr) {
    var arrLength = arr.length;
    if(arrLength < 3) {
        return false;
    }

    for(var i = 1; i < arrLength; i++) {
        if(i + 1 < arrLength && arr[i-1] == arr[i] && arr[i] == arr[i+ 1]) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```